# redshift_connector - How to set query group to queries executed in cursor.execute() method?

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to set query group to queries executed in cursor.execute() method?

**Example:**

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='<myhost>',
    database='dev',
    user='<myuser>',
    password='<mypassword>'
 )

with conn .cursor() as cursor:
    
    query = """
    set query_group to 'test';

    select col1, col2, col3 from table where col4='xyz';
    """

    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)

conn .close()
```

I'm trying to set/assign query_group 'test' to the select query to be executed. But getting below error:

**redshift_connector.error.ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement', 'F': '../src/pg/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c', 'L': '3910', 'R': 'exec_parse_message'}**

Please let me know how I can assign query_group to queries executed using cursor.execute() method

psycopg2 library supports multiple statements to be executed using cursor.execute() method.

Comment: Could you give it a try by removing the semicolon `;` I am not sure if this would work but worth a shot.